# 6/11までにAPIキーの設定が完了しない場合の解像度について

Tags: google-maps

プログラムの質問ではないのですが、タイトルにあるように、6/11までに設定が完了しない場合、どの程度の解像度で地図が表示されるのか、教えていただけますか。
ECサイトで顧客向けに、店舗の位置を示しています。

何かサンプルがあれば、より助かります。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google の発表では、以下のようになっています。解像度以上に“for development purposes only.”という透かしが入るのが見た目としてはよくないでしょうね。

> At that time, keyless calls to the Maps JavaScript API and Street View API will return low-resolution maps watermarked with “for development purposes only.”

サンプルとか求めなくても、APIキーの設定は10分もあればできる作業です。さったと作業をしてしまいましょう。店舗であれば、登録されていなければGoogleマイビジネスで登録して Google Maps Embed API の方を使えば完全に無料です。

Comment: Yasuhiro Niji様、ありがとうございます。ベンダーに連絡して早急に作業を進めます。